# Ternary conditional operator without the middle expression

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, conditional-operator, elvis-operator

I realized recently that you can use the ternary operator in GCC and clang without a middle (`?:` or `?   :` works) and it will insert the first expression into the middle:

```
// outputs 2
cout << (2 ?: 4);
// outputs 3
cout << (0 ?  : 3);
```

Where is this in the standard?  I looked and didn't see anything about it.

Comment: It does not insert the first expression into the middle. It uses the _result_ of the first expression in the middle. So if the first expression is a function, the function is not executed twice.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It isn't in the standard *at all*.

What you are observing is a GCC extension: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html

If you omit it, its value is taken from the first operand prior to contextual conversion to `bool`.
The extensions value lies in not repeating side-effects and reducing the source-codes size.

Comment: Thats what I thought thanks.  Makes sense its present in clang then as well.

Comment: Is it a good idea to have C++ code that works only with GCC/Clang ?

Comment: @Ilya It's a good idea to write as clean and portable code as you reasonably can without expending too much effort or unacceptably compromising your performance. In short, almost never.

Comment: In that case, you would have a non-portable, less obvious (because non-standard) code on one hand, and a little more verbose (one more bool perhaps) on the other hand. Would you choose the first option ?

Comment: @Ilya That small amount of extra-typing is a small price for being standards-conformant. My previous comment was a bit more general.